Can I dispute a late payment caused by a payment Posting Delay?
I fell behind on my car payments with Chase Bank, but I always make sure not to let it go 30 days late. My payment is due on the 21st of every month. I made my payment on the 20th, which was a Saturday. The agent who took the payment told me the payment would post on Monday, the 22nd, but they would backdate it to reflect the actual payment date. A few days later I received notification that my payment was received 32 days late. I spoke with a manager and was told they are not open on weekends, so payments that are made over the weekend are recorded as being received on the next business day. Is this something that I can dispute because technically I made my payment on the 29th day? Chase Auto does not make goodwill adjustments.

The agent who took the payment told me - what do you mean by "agent"? A bank teller? Generally, Saturday is not a banking day for Chase and all weekend transactions post on Monday. Due dates falling on weekends usually get days added until the next business day, but if you're already past due date then its calendar days.

The mistake here was letting yourself fall into arrears in the first place. You can't expect a further grace period when you are already into the grace period. Pay the penalty and learn from it.

Chase has a resource page with FAQs for auto loans. There they post this, at the bottom:

Payments made on a business day (Monday-Friday, excluding holidays) from a Chase deposit account by 11 PM ET or from a non-Chase deposit account by 8 PM ET will be credited on the same business day. Payments made on weekends, holidays or after the cutoff time will be credited the next business day. If you miss the earlier cutoff time, you can make a same-day payment at 1-800-346-8915 until 10:30 PM ET on a business day.

This addresses the situation you're having exactly. You made a payment on a weekend, and it was credited the next business day, just as they promised.
It appears that the manager you spoke to is correct. This disclaimer was on that website, I'm guessing, for a while and it is your responsibility to know when to make your payments.
I don't think there's a case for you to dispute, but you can ask nicely and maybe they'll waive the late fees or reporting to the bureaus for this occurrence. They don't have to.
